Extract information through SQLite and Python


I am working with a DataBase in Sqlite and Python with the table that is attached.
I am interested in get a query that give me a list with an unique item in IDFrom, for those unique items, the VoltMag, and the kV. I am no interested in other information in the table. I have tried with the following query, but I have not get the expected result.
I appreciate any help.
Regards,



IDFrom
Type
kV
VoltMag
IDTo
LFMW




LVBus
Load
0.47999999
97.353271484375
Sub3 Swgr
-0.476513087749481


LVBus
0
0
0
Bus5
0.123355090618134


Main Bus
Swng
34.5
100
Sub2A
3.65306186676025


Main Bus
0
0
0
Sub2B
-1.56734025478363


Main Bus
XF3W
0
0
Sub 3
0


Sub2A
Load
13.8000001907349
99.2764282226562
Bus7
2.71204876899719


Sub2A
0
0
0
Main Bus
1.79826784133911


Sub2B
Gen
13.8000001907349
101
Bus6
1.79826784133911


Sub2B
0
0
0
Sub 3
1.6838458776474


Sub2B
XF3W
0
0
Main Bus
0


Sub22
Load
3.45000004768372
96.6335220336914
Bus7
-2.69958877563477


Sub23
Load
3.45000004768372
100.332984924316
Bus23A
0.524362742900848


Sub23
0
0
0
Bus6
-1.79444992542267


Sub23
Load
3.45000004768372
100.332984924316
VFD2
1.27008724212647


UPS-1
Swng
0.479999989271164
100
Bus4
0.0918000042438507


VFD2
Swng
3.45000004768372
100
Bus8
1.27008724212647



def Vmag(conn):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(r"SELECT VoltMag FROM LFR WHERE TYPE !=0 AND kV !=0;")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    return rows

def NomkV(conn):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(r"SELECT kV FROM LFR WHERE TYPE !=0 AND kV !=0;")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    return rows

def BusName(conn):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(r"SELECT IDFrom FROM LFR WHERE TYPE !=0 AND kV !=0;")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    return rows

I would like to have three list as result:



IDFrom




LVBus


Main Bus


Sub2A


Sub2B


Sub22


Sub23


UPS-1


VFD2






kV




0.479999989


34.5


13.80000019


13.80000019


3.450000048


3.450000048


0.479999989


3.450000048






VoltMag




97.35327148


100


99.27642822


101


96.63352203


100.3329849


100


100




It would be useful to have a the result of .dump LFR  using the sqlite3 utility to re-create your database.

What are you getting instead of the expected results?

Why are you expecting a different number of results from each query? The WHERE clause matches the same rows in all of them, so it should return the same number of results.

I think you want SELECT DISTINCT and use it in a subquery to display only the column you want, or just use it alone in one function (AsOneQuery below) to fetch all the interesting unique column values:
import sqlite3

def create_db():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE LFR (IDFrom,Type,kV,VoltMag,IDTo,LFMWE);')
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO LFR VALUES('LVBus','Load',0.47999998999999998749,97.353271484374999996,'Sub3 Swgr',-0.47651308774948097912);")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO LFR VALUES('LVBus',0,0,0,'Bus5',0.123355090618134);")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO LFR VALUES('Main Bus','Swng',34.5,100,'Sub2A',3.65306186676025);")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO LFR VALUES('Main Bus',0,0,0,'Sub2B',-1.56734025478363);")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO LFR VALUES('Main Bus','XF3W',0,0,'Sub 3',0);")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO LFR VALUES('Sub2A','Load',13.8000001907349,99.2764282226562,'Bus7',2.71204876899719);")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO LFR VALUES('Sub2A',0,0,0,'Main Bus',1.79826784133911);")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO LFR VALUES('Sub2B','Gen',13.8000001907349,101,'Bus6',1.79826784133911);")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO LFR VALUES('Sub2B',0,0,0,'Sub 3',1.6838458776474);")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO LFR VALUES('Sub2B','XF3W',0,0,'Main Bus',0);")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO LFR VALUES('Sub22','Load',3.45000004768372,96.6335220336914,'Bus7',-2.69958877563477);")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO LFR VALUES('Sub23','Load',3.45000004768372,100.332984924316,'Bus23A',0.524362742900848);")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO LFR VALUES('Sub23',0,0,0,'Bus6',-1.79444992542267);")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO LFR VALUES('Sub23','Load',3.45000004768372,100.332984924316,'VFD2',1.27008724212647);")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO LFR VALUES('UPS-1','Swng',0.479999989271164,100,'Bus4',0.0918000042438507);")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO LFR VALUES('VFD2','Swng',3.45000004768372,100,'Bus8',1.27008724212647);")
    conn.commit()
    return conn

def Vmag(conn):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(r"SELECT VoltMag FROM (SELECT DISTINCT IDFrom,VoltMag from LFR WHERE TYPE !=0 AND kV !=0);")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    return rows

def NomkV(conn):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(r"SELECT kV FROM (SELECT DISTINCT IDFrom,kV FROM LFR WHERE TYPE !=0 AND kV !=0);")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    return rows

def BusName(conn):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(r"SELECT DISTINCT IDFrom FROM LFR WHERE TYPE !=0 AND kV !=0;")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    return rows

def AsOneQuery(conn):
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(r"SELECT DISTINCT IDFrom,kV,VoltMag FROM LFR WHERE TYPE !=0 AND kV !=0;")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    return rows

conn = create_db()
for row, in BusName(conn):
    print(row)
print()
for row, in NomkV(conn):
    print(row)
print()
for row, in Vmag(conn):
    print(row)
print()
for IDFrom, kv, VoltMag in AsOneQuery(conn):
    print(f'{IDFrom:9}{kv:18}{VoltMag:18}')

Output:
LVBus
Main Bus
Sub2A
Sub2B
Sub22
Sub23
UPS-1
VFD2

0.47999999
34.5
13.8000001907349
13.8000001907349
3.45000004768372
3.45000004768372
0.479999989271164
3.45000004768372

97.353271484375
100
99.2764282226562
101
96.6335220336914
100.332984924316
100
100

LVBus            0.47999999   97.353271484375
Main Bus               34.5               100
Sub2A      13.8000001907349  99.2764282226562
Sub2B      13.8000001907349               101
Sub22      3.45000004768372  96.6335220336914
Sub23      3.45000004768372  100.332984924316
UPS-1     0.479999989271164               100
VFD2       3.45000004768372               100

